# googlemapsが、atom起動後1回目のコード実行でしか機能しない　ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googlemaps'

Tags: python, google-maps, google-api, atom-editor, pip

**環境（簡易）**
osはmac、エディタはatom、言語はpython、コード実行は、atom-runnerを使用

**やっていること**
pythonにgooglemapsをインポートし、googleのGeocoding APIを使い、住所から緯度経度を取得しようとしています。

**問題**
コードは正しく動作し、googlemapsから欲しい情報が取得できます。
しかし、atom起動後の、1回目のコード実行でしか、それが機能しません。
なぜか2回目以降のコード実行では、エラーが出て機能しません。
1回目のコード実行が完了後、再度コードを実行すると、下記エラーが出ます。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/************/test_geocode.py", line 1, in <module>
    import googlemaps
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googlemaps'
```

その後は、何度実行を試みても、同じ上記エラーが出るだけです。
ただし、atomを再起動すれば、また1回目の実行時のみ、情報を取得することができます。

**該当のコード**

```
import googlemaps

googleapikey = '自分のAPI_KEY'
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key=googleapikey)

result = gmaps.geocode('任意の住所')
lat = result[0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"]
lng = result[0]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"]
print(result)
print (lat,lng)
```

上記"問題"の項目に記載の通り、コードは合っているはず　です

**試したこと**

- このコードを、iPadのPythonistaというアプリで実行すると、問題無く、何度でも実行、情報を取得できた
  　→やはりコードは合っているはず。
- `pip install wheel` (ネットに情報があった為試したが変わらず)
- `pip uninstall googlemaps`とし、`easy_install googlemaps`を実行した
  (stack over runに情報があった為試してみた。結果変わらず)
- atom再起動
- パソコンの再起動

同じエラー（No module named 'googlemaps'）に関する情報は見つけたが、同じ現象に関する情報は見つからず。

**環境詳細**

- パソコン：macbookpro macOS Catalina 10.15.6
- エディタ：atom 1.50.0
- コード実行：atom-runner 2.7.1
- python 3.8.5
- pip 20.2.2
- pyenv 1.2.20
- googlemaps 4.42

Answer (score 0):

### 解決しました

### 結論

コード実行に使用していたパッケージのatom-runnerが原因でした。

コード実行のパッケージを、atom-runnerからscript に変更したら解決しました。
atom-runnerは、アンインストールする必要がありました。
atom-runnerがインストールされたままだと、scriptでも同じ現象が起きます。
（理由は不明）

### やったこと

1. Atomを完全削除して再インストール
2. パッケージatom-runnerをインストール
3. atom-runnerでコードを実行
4. また同じ現象が起きた
5. もう一度同じ方法でatomを完全削除、再インストール
6. 今度はパッケージscriptをインストール
7. パッケージscriptでコードを実行
8. 解決
9. 試しに、もう一度atom-runnerをインストール
10. 同じ問題が、atom-runner、script両方のコード実行時に起きるようになる
11. atom-runnerをアンインストール
12. scriptで再度コード実行してみる
13. 解決

https://qiita.com/akira_ak/questions/a44579fe3b6201cabfba#answer-c647db82f30ff02a7c22